Time Complexity of the Iterative Version of the Subsequence Question
What will be the time complexity of the Code below, as my teacher said the time complexity will be O(N2^N).
My question, as per my understanding of how T.C(which might be very wrong, so please don't judge) is calculated by seeing how many times the loop will be running as the input grows.
So as per my thinking, T.C should be O(N2^(N-1)), as when we will process 3 it will run 4 times and when it will process 4 it will run 8 times.
Please help me understanding it. Moreover, my teacher is not responding to my questions, so that's why I cam over here.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        List<List<Integer>> ans = subset(arr);
        for(List<Integer> list: ans)
        {
            System.out.println(list);
        }

    }

    static List<List<Integer>> subset(int[] arr)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<>();

        outer.add(new ArrayList<>());

        for(int num: arr)
        {
            int size = outer.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                List<Integer> internal = new ArrayList<>(outer.get(i));
                internal.add(num);
                outer.add(internal);
            }
        }

        return outer;
    }

}


O(N2^(N-1)) and O(N2^(N)) are the same thing. Move on.

@user24714692 thankyou sir for the reply, but can you just tell me one thing if my understanding is right that it should be O(N2^(N-1)), I get it is both same but just wanted to clear my head

Both O(N2^(N-1)) and O(N2^(N)) are very large and very close. Therefore, for practical applications, it does not really matter. But for the sake of "theory", see here.
